# Django вывод картинки из базы

Tags: python, django

Картинки были внесены в базу через админку, помогите вывести
путь /broom/static/img

**settings.py:**

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'img/')
MEDIA_URL = '/img/'
```

**models.py:**

```
class Images(models.Model):
    model_img = models.ImageField(upload_to='static/img')
```

**views.py:**

```
def index(request):
    num_img = Images.objects.all().count()

    return render(request, 'index.html', context={'num_img': num_img})
```

**шаблон:**

```
{% block content %}

    {% for i in num_img %}
        <a href="{{ i.model_img.url }}"></a>
    {% endfor %}

{% endblock %}
```

**urls.py:**

```
urlpatterns = [
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
path('broom/', include('broom.urls')),
path('', RedirectView.as_view(url='/broom/', permanent=True)),
]
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Ваши изображения сохраняются в:

`img -> static -> img`

Вам лучше прописать так:

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

И в `models` прописать:

```
model_img = models.ImageField(upload_to='img/')
```

Тогда ваши загруженные изображения будут сохранятся в:

`media -> img` Что более удобней.

2. Из `views` Вы отправляете `count`, то есть общее количество всех фотографий, если вы хотите отправить сами фотографии, стоило бы прописать:

`num_img = Images.objects.all()`

И в `html` использовать не тег `<a>`, а тег `img`:

```
{% for i in num_img %}
    <img src="{{ i.model_img.url }}">
{% endfor %}
```